# Checkbox state if not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I so far have the following code but I am having an issue and thats how can create the "state" if the `data-id` has not been set as `checked`?

**Code:**

```
        $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
             if ($(this).is(":checked")) checkbox.push($(this).data("id"))
        })
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
             if ($(this).is(":checked")) checkbox.push($(this).data("id"))
             {
                $state = 1; 
             }else{
                $state = 0;
             }
        })
```

Comment: data-id in this case is an arbitrary attribute, separate from "checked" property. What are you trying to achieve? If "data-id" doesn't exist - create it? If so - what should be put there - 1 for checked checkbox, 0 for unchecked?

Comment: What do you want to do with your `$state` variable? There's not much point setting it inside a loop because it'll get overwritten with each iteration and end up recording the state of the last checkbox only. As an aside, note that `if (this.checked) ...` is easier to type, easier to read, and more efficient than `if ($(this).is(":checked"))...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code might be like:

```
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
         if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
         {
            checkbox.push($(this).data("id"));
            $state = 1; 
         }else{
            $state = 0;
         }
    })
```